# samsung backlight

Tags: kernel, samsung, backlight

I have a Samsung Series 7 Chronos (700Z5C-S02UB) and a couple of kernel updates ago (I'm currently on 3.5.0-25-generic ), I lost the keyboard backlight support.
Any idea on how to turn it back on?

NOTE:
I've already had samsung-tools, I've re-installed but still doesn't work

EDIT:
I manage to get it working (somehow). What I found is: the ambient light autodetect works, but it seems to be unable to control the level of brightness. If I boot windows and set it to high, it works in Ubuntu
(it might be just a coincidence tho)

Answer (score 5):

Is there a /sys/class/leds/samsung::kbd_backlight?

If so, try

```
echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

It could be any number between 0 and 8 indicating the level of brightness of the keyboard backlight.

**Otherwise**, try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samsung-tools samsung-laptop
```

Reboot, then

```
echo 8 > /sys/devices/platform/samsung/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: nope, I have /sys/class/leds/phy0-led . Not really sure to what device it belongs, but trying to set it didn't do anything either

Comment: okay, try the second method.

Comment: no luck either :(

Comment: I think you may need to do this. Try opening `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` save. Run in terminal `sudo update-grub` and restart.

Comment: Ok, now is working, but I have only "quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux "
I have a theory, tomorrow I'll test it. Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: I have been playing with this on my Samsung Series 9 900X4D-A03 I tried the grub  [GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"] but found this works better on my machine. [GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=vendor"]